# using STDOUT from within gdb

Tags: c, emacs, gdb

I have a function that pretty prints a data structure, its function prototype is:

```
void print_mode(FILE *fp, Mode *mode);
```

the FILE* allows you to redirect the output to anywhere you want, e.g. stdout, stderr, a file etc. Mode is the data structure

I am trying to call this function from within gdb and want the output to be directed to the gdb console window, stdout?

I have tried:

```
(gdb) p print_mode(STDOUT,fragment_mode)
No symbol "STDOUT" in current context.
(gdb) p print_mode(stdout,fragment_mode)
$17 = void
```

neither of which work

any ideas how i can get the output of the function to display in the gdb console?

should add - I am using gdb within emacs 24.2.1 under linux

Comment: Try looking at `info terminal`, `run > redirect-file` and `tty device-name`.  There will be device names that are the equivalent of stdin, stdout, ala /dev/tty

Comment: Try `call print_mode(stdout,fragment_mode)` instead of `p print_mode(stdout,fragment_mode)`?

Comment: Could `STDOUT` be a macro? Find out to what it expands.

Comment: @anishsane: In terms what the program itself prints out `print` and `call` shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Let's check whether stdout has a sensible value. Does `call fprintf(stdout, "test %d\n", 5)` within gdb produce output?

Comment: @alk, I also expect the same. Before I knew `call` command, I had a habit of using `print` command & it should work normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STDOUT` seems to be macro, which is not know to GDB, as handled prior to compilation by the pre-preprocessor.

Using `stdout` should do the job.

However the function `print_mode()` simply does not seem to print out anything.

In terms what's being printed to the console by the program being debugged, GDB's commands `print`and `call` should not make a difference.

For details on this you might like to read here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Calling.html

---

An issue might be that `stdout` by default is line buffered, so output would not occur before detecting a linefeed and `print_mode()` perhaps does not send a linefeed (`\n`).

To test this just use `stderr` as output file, as the latter isn't buffered:

```
p print_mode(stderr, fragment_mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear - silly mistake. You're right, `stdout` does do the job.

I forgot that having upgraded from emacs 23 to 24, the way gdb works has changed in as much as it now opens a separate buffer `*input/output of program-name*` to which it redirects the output of the program being debugged. In the prior version of emacs it was all displayed in the same, single gdb buffer.

So my second attempt was actually working, I was just looking in the wrong place so didn't see the output